# Writing unit-test and need to control the c++ linker

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, mocking, linker

I am writing unit-tests for a C++ class that has dependencies on 3rd-party C and C++ libraries, as well as 1st-party C libraries. I am running into trouble, because I want the class under test to consume a mocked 3rd-party C library and the test runner to consume the REAL 3rd-party C library.

1. I am writing unit-tests, and the class under test has a dependency on `libx`.
2. I have created a `libmockx` which allows me to test parameters and inject return values.
3. The class under test, needs to link to `libmockx` so I can inspect and control it's behavior.
4. The unit test application, needs to link to `libx` in order to formulate/parse `libx` data types.

Which pattern or method is used to link the test runner to `libx`, the class under test to `libmockx`, then link the test-runner to the class under test? Many solutions discuss letting the linker do the "dirty work", but `ld` has 100s of parameters and I don't know how to make it work.

Currently, I have redefinition errors for all the mock implementations, and I need a way to work around it (whether that involves the linker or not).

> **EDIT BELOW:** *(in response to comments)*

Imagine 7 files:

- `test.cpp` - the test runner
- `object.cpp` - the `object` under test
- `object.hpp` - the `object` header
- `mock-parameters.h` - provide mock parameter access to tests
- `mock-x.c` - the mock implementation of `x`
- `x.c` - the `x` implementation
- `x.h` - the `x` header

Before I needed to instantiate and manipulate `x` objects, I was able to compile my test with a single call to `g++`:

```
g++ test.cpp object.cpp mock_x.c
```

I am trying to add a test to `test.cpp`, that will supply and test an `x` object result value. Now, I need to link `test.cpp` against `x.c` while still linking `object.cpp` against `mock_x.c`.

When I add `x.c` to the compilation list, I get the following (expected) error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDVQxtN.o: in function `set_foo(X*, int)':
mock-x.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `set_foo(X*, int)'; /tmp/cc3t8CjP.o:x.c:(.text+0x14): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**`x.h`**

```c
#ifndef X_H
#define X_H

typedef struct X {
    int foo;
    char bar;
} X;

X * create_x (void);
int set_foo (X *, int);
char set_bar (X *, char);
void delete_x (X *);

#endif // X_H
```

**`x.c`**

```c
#include "x.h"

#include "stdlib.h"

X * create_x (void) {
    return (X *)malloc(sizeof(X));
}

int set_foo (X * x, int i) {
    x->foo = i;
    return i;
}

char set_bar (X * x, char c) {
    x->bar = c;
    return c;
}

void delete_x (X * x) {
    free(x);
}
```

**`mock-x.c`**

```c
#include "x.h"
#include "mock-parameters.h"

Set_foo_params set_foo_params;

int set_foo (X * x, int i) {
    // Stash parameter(s)
    set_foo_params.x = x;
    set_foo_params.i = i;

    return set_foo_params.result;
}
```

**`object.hpp`**

```cpp
#ifndef OBJECT_HPP
#define OBJECT_HPP

#include "x.h"

class Object {
    public:
    void embed_x(X *);
    int increment_foo(int);

    private:
    X * _x;
};

#endif // OBJECT_HPP
```

**`object.cpp`**

```cpp
#include "object.hpp"

void Object::embed_x (X * x) {
    _x = x;
}

int Object::increment_foo (int i) {
    ++i;
    return set_foo(_x, i);
}
```

**`mock-parameters.h`**

```c
#include "x.h"

typedef struct Set_foo_params {
    X * x;
    int i;
    int result;
} Set_foo_params;

extern Set_foo_params set_foo_params;
```

**`test.cpp`**

```cpp
#include "object.hpp"
#include "mock-parameters.h"

int test_object_update_foo_correctly_invokes_x_set_foo (void) {
    int result;
    Object object;

    // Setup
    X * x = create_x();
    object.embed_x(x);

    // Execute
    object.increment_foo(7);

    // Test
    if (8 == set_foo_params.i) {
        result = 0;
    } else {
        result = 1;
    }

    delete_x(x);
    return result;
}

int test_object_update_foo_correctly_returns_x_set_foo_result (void) {
    int result;
    Object object;

    // Setup
    X * x = create_x();
    object.embed_x(x);
    set_foo_params.result = 5;

    // Execute
    int output = object.increment_foo(0);

    // Test
    if (5 == output) {
        result = 0;
    } else {
        result = 2;
    }

    delete_x(x);
    return result;
}

int main (void) {
    int result;

    result |= test_object_update_foo_correctly_invokes_x_set_foo();
    result |= test_object_update_foo_correctly_returns_x_set_foo_result();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Recommend adding the build tool you're using to the question. It will directly impact the solutions offered.

Comment: I'm compiling by hand at the moment. Imagine 6 files, `test.cpp`, `object.cpp`, `mock_x.c`, `x.c`, `object.hpp`, `x.h`.

Comment: In that case you should just have to specify the different library on the command line. Perhaps adding an example of what you are currently doing to the question will shake loose answers.

Comment: Just an idea: How about using the `--wrap` option to intercept all calls to the library? You can use an external flag to decide in a wrapper function to mock the function or call the real function. -- Would you mind to provide a [example], please?

Comment: Does the functionality of your <x.h> API (with different x.c and mock-x.c implementations) that is used from your object.c and the functionality used from your test.cpp overlap?

Comment: @SergeDundich Yes, there is a single API call that is used in both `test.cpp` and `object.cpp` .

Answer (score 0):

Since you clarified that your **object.c** and **test.c** use the same functions - but should use different implementations - the only way is to separate those functions in some way. According to ODR (One Definition Rule of C++ programming language) you cannot have two different implementations of the same function/object.

So the only way is to create two separate functions/objects (with a separate names). You can use different names or put the same names in different namespaces.

Example:

**x.h**:

```
#ifndef X_H
#define X_H

#ifdef X_DEBUG
#define X mock_x
#else
#define X x
#endif

namespace X {

int foo();

}

#endif // X_H
```

**x.cpp**:

```
namespace x {

int foo()
{
    int res = -1;
    // rightful implementation
    return res;
}

}
```

**mock-x.cpp**:

```
namespace mock_x {

int foo()
{
    int res = -1;
    // mock implementation
    return res;
}

}
```

**object.cpp**:

```
#define X_DEBUG
#include <x.h>

int obj_bar()
{
    int res = X::foo(); // uses mock implementation
    return res;
}

}
```

**test.cpp**:

```
#include <x.h>

int test_bar()
{
    int res = X::foo(); // uses real implementation
    return res;
}

}
```

Obviously this approach is scalable - you can put any number of classes/function/objects in this **namespace X**. Common functionality may be defined inline in the header **<x.h>** and separate functionality in corresponding modules **x.c** and **mock-x.c**.

**In general:**

I would definitely look in the direction of creating mock-x implementation as a distinct set of linker symbols. This is definitely much more controllable and flexible approach. You can even use original x API implementation from your mock-x functionality - e.g. as a fallback when appropriate.

**EDIT:**

For your specific newly added example code.

**mock-x.c:**

```
#include "x.h"
#include "mock-parameters.h"

Set_foo_params set_foo_params;

int mock_set_foo (X * x, int i) {
    // Stash parameter(s)
    set_foo_params.x = x;
    set_foo_params.i = i;

    return set_foo_params.result;
}
```

The rest of the files are unchanged.
GCC should compile **object.cpp** separately with command:

```
g++ -Dset_foo=mock_set_foo -c object.cpp -o object.o
g++ test.cpp object.o x.c mock_x.c
```

GCC option `-Dset_foo=mock_set_foo` works the same as

```
#define set_foo mock_set_foo
```

in the beginning of each source file in command line after this option.
This option is widely used for compile-time configuration purposes.

Comment: `x.c` and `x.h` are from a 3rd party library I do not have control over. I don't think this implementation will work, but thank you for trying.

Comment: @Zak This changes not much at all. If you have no control over **<x.h>** and **x.c** then you may simply write something like **<my_x.h>** where you can (possibly conditionally) **#define** all names you need to mock to any alternative names you like before **#include**-ing **<x.h>**. Use alternative names in **mock-x.c** to define alternative implementations. After that you may **#include <my_x.h>** instead of **<x.h>** in **object.c** (while still **#include**-ing **<x.h>** in **test.c**). Do you need code example for that or you figure this yourself?

Comment: I understand what you are getting at. However, I am not at liberty to take such a heavy handed approach. The code I'm working on is already in production, so I am not allowed to modify it or add new files.

My goal is to utilize the linker, so I can get these tests in place. At that time, I will refactor the code base to make it test friendly, and I will not have to go to such lengths to compile the unit tests.

Comment: @Zak You put very strange limitations to a scope of possible solutions. All your claims combined sound contradictory. Obviously you shouldn't change behavior of production code (unless you intend to do that). But what prevents you from changing the code for your unit test? How can you possibly write unit test (or anything new) without adding new files or new code? Your unit test shouldn't run in production, right? Alternatively maybe you could use some linking trick with creating separate dynamically loadable binaries for **test.c** and **object.c** but I would advise against it - not easier.

Comment: To clarify, I can add as many additional test/mock files as needed, and I can change the unit tests as much as I like. In this example, I cannot modify `x.h`, `x.c`, `object.hpp`, or `object.cpp`.

Comment: @Zak But you can compile `object.cpp` with the options of your choice, right? You have no obligation to use it in already compiled binary same as production, correct?

Comment: @Zak Then to implement the solution in the spirit of my answer you may just use the `gcc` option `-include` (or equivalent for your compiler) to include the header that contains x API names redefinitions to mock variants. Or use `-D` options instead if number of symbols to redefine is small.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those compiler options, can you include those compile commands in your answer?

Comment: @Zak I've added one possible solution for the example that you recently posted in the question edits.